# form action not hits correct method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please check the MVC view code bellow. However i have set form action="ProductEditUploadProcess" but my form submit not hits "ProductEditUploadProcess" method its hiting another method called "ProductEdit" which method returns just view of that page. The Picture will more clarify you.

[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]

MVC View:

```
<form action="ProductEditUploadProcess" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@ViewBag.Product.ProductId"/>
        Select Thumbnail image:
        <input type="file" name="Thumbnail" id="ThumbnailToUpload"><br />
        @*Select Banner image:
        <input type="file" name="Banner" id="BannerToUpload"><br />
        Select Product Zip File:
        <input type="file" name="ProductZip" id="ProductZipToUpload"><br />*@
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Upload Files" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Always use the `HtmlHelper` methods to generate the correct html - `@using (Html.BeingForm("ProductEditUploadProcess", "Administrator", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))` (and do the same for your inputs! and why do you have 3 file inputs when your method only accepts the first one

Comment: forget reset 3 file input. i will handle it later. i need to hit the correct method just for now. and i did same html helper too but it does same @StephenMuecke

Comment: Impossible, unless you have some other code you have not shown causing it to hit the `ProductEdit` method

Comment: what other code else you want to see then? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Since it would be impossible to hit `ProductEdit` with a post, I'm guessing your have that html wrapped inside another `<form>` element (i.e. nested forms, which is invalid html and not supported)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form action must be "/ControllerName/ActionName"

Answer (score 0):

in your form action also mention controller name too. since your view is with name as ProductEdit, if you don't provide enough parameters to it. it will only look to controller for that method which view have same name.